# How to calculate product prices cheaper than current row

Tags: sql, sql-server

Need help with an SQL query.

I have a products table... Fields are...

```
product_id
product_name
product_price
```

I want to show all products and have an additional column that shows how many products are cheaper than the current product. So, for example....

```
product_id     product_name     product_price     Products_cheaper
1              product 1        1.50              0
2              product 2        6.50              2
3              product 3        2.50              1
4              product 4        10.50             3
```

Any suggestions on this SQL query?

Using SQL Server. Also, if products are equal then it's 0.

Comment: how about if there are same product_price value? also, please tag the RDBMS you are using.

Comment: @FerdinandGaspar I updated my OP.

Comment: i mean, for example if product 5 will be 6.50 same as with product 2, how would the numbering for the other products will be affected?

Comment: The products whos price is greater than 6.50, their products_cheaper column would be increased by 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT product_id,
       product_name,
       product_price,
       RANK() OVER (ORDER BY product_price) - 1 AS product_cheaper
  FROM products
 ORDER BY product_id
```

Result (I added the sample I used on my comment)

```
product_id  product_name    product_price   product_cheaper
1           product 1       1.50            0
2           product 2       6.50            2
3           product 3       2.50            1
4           product 4       10.50           4
5           product 5       6.50            2
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!